# Getting the same value in an php button in javascript with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm working on adding a reason as to why someone's request got denied on my website.
I want the submit reason button to have the same value as the reject button that reveals the textarea to add a reason. I know that I have to use AJAX but I don't know how or what to use.

This is the javascript code that I'm using to reveal the popup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openForm() {
        document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
    }

    function closeForm() {
        document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

This is my html code for the popup

```
<div class="form-container" id="myForm">
    <form method="post" class="reason-popup">
        <h1>Reden</h1>
        <textarea placeholder="Type message..." id="rejectReasonText" name="rejectReasonText"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit" name="rejectReasonSubmit" value="<?php echo $leaveRequestId; ?>">Verzenden</button>
        <button type="button" class="btnCancel" onclick="closeForm()">Sluiten</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="selectedUser" value="<?php echo $selectedUser; ?>">
    </form>
</div>
```

And this is my php code

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                if((isTeamLeider() || isAdmin()) && $_SESSION['user']['team'] == $row["team"]) {
                    echo '<tr><form method="post">';
                    echo '<td>' . $row["name"]              . "<br>"        . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row["startDate"]         . "<br>"        . $row["endDate"] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row["startTime"]         . "<br>"        . $row["endTime"] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td style="text-align : center;">' . $row["reason"]           . "<br>"        .  '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row["specialLeave"]      . "<br>"        . '</td>';
                    echo '<td><button name="accept" value="'. $row["ID"]    .'" class="btn">accepteren</button></td>';
                    echo '</form>';
                }

                echo '<td><button name="reject" value="'      . $row["ID"]    .'"  onclick="openForm()" class="btn">weigeren</button></td>';
                echo '</form></tr>';
            } 

                if (isset($_POST['reject'])) {
                    global $db, $leaveRequestId;
                    $_SESSION['leaveRequestId'] = $_POST['reject'];
                    $leaveRequestId = $_SESSION['leaveRequestId'];

                }


            if (isset($_POST['rejectReasonSubmit'])) {
                global $db, $leaveRequestId;
                $rejectReason = e($_POST["rejectReasonText"]);

            }
```

So I want the value of rejectreasonsubmit to be the same as the reject button.

Comment: If you just want to change the value of a button which is already on your page, you should be able to do it just with JavaScript. It's unclear why you'd need to use AJAX or post back to the server for that.

Comment: I don't really want to change the values of the button I just want the reject button and the rejectReasonSubmit button to have the same value because when I press the reject button it has the value of a certain ID from a table in the database, and then it opens up my textarea with another button and I need that button to also have the same ID value.

Comment: "I don't really want to change the values of the button"...but your question is asking specifically how to change the value of the the rejectReasonSubmit button so it matches the one which was clicked... so I'm not really sure what you're trying to say here.

Comment: I guess I do want to change the values I just got confused for a bit, but how would I be able to give them the same value then in javascript?

Comment: You get the value from the first element (the clicked one). Then you assign that value to the other element. You can find syntax / examples of of both operations online fairly easily.

Comment: I tried that already by using the $leaverequestId variable as the value of the button in the html but it didn't work, even though when I echo the variable in the reject button it does give me the right value

Comment: that's because PHP runs on the server and does not know what was clicked - when your openForm() function runs, PHP does not execute at that time - nothing is sent to the server. Like I said, use Javascript instead.